# ASP.NET - Page.Form.Action error

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my local development server, I am running version 2.0.50727.4955 on the live server I am running 2.0.50727.42.

On my live server I get:

Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' does not contain a definition for 'Action'

On my development server everything works fine. Is this a .NET version issue or something else? Is there a way to make this work on my liver server with its current .Net version? Is there a way to upgrade from 2.0.50727.42 to 2.0.50727.4955?

Thanks

EDIT (Code):

```
    if (Request.PathInfo.Length != 0)
    {
        string reqPath = Request.PathInfo;
        string raw = Request.RawUrl;
        string url = Request.Url.ToString();
        if (reqPath.Length > 0)
            url = url.Replace(reqPath, "");
        if (raw.Length > 0)
            url = url.Replace(raw, "");

        litBasePath.Text = "<base href=\"" + url + "\">";
        Page.Form.Attributes["Action"] = raw;
    }
```

EDIT (Local Setup)

This is my local setup. I am not getting any compile errors when i run this locally.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See update to my answer.  2.0 SP2 introduced the HtmlForm.Action property.  It wasn't available in 2.0 RTM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlForm.Action does not exist in the unpatched 2.0 framework.  Only in 2.0 sp2+.  My guess is that your local environment you're building as a 3.5 app and using libraries that do not exist in your live environment.

In order set/change Action, I believe you need to use `Page.Form.Attributes["action"] = "Some URL Here"`

Or, if it's possible, patch your server (recommended) or install the .NET 3.5 Framework. in your live environment.

Comment: My local site is set to use my DefaultAppPool. The DefaultAppPool is set to use .NET Framework v2.0. How would this work on my local development server in v2.0? Also I've checked my target framework is set to ".NET Framework 2.0"

Comment: That's because .NET 3.5 uses the 2.0 runtime.  IIS doesn't need to know any different.  You need to check what version of the framework your app is building as.

Comment: How can 2 version of .NET use the same runtime? I did double check my website properties in Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express and it is set to ".NET Framework 2.0"

Comment: The runtime is just the code that interprets the IL built by the compiler.  There were no huge changes in the IL between 2.0 and 3.5, so no need for a new runtime.  .NET 4 uses a new version of the runtime, though.

Comment: How interesting is that... just fired up VS WD 2010, set the build to 2.0 and it let me use it.

Comment: If you replace your usage of Page.Form.Action with my recommendation above, it should fix your problem though.

Comment: I've added screenshots of my config. I don't think anything is setup wrong. I'll use your recommendation above (it works i tested it) but does this mean I could be using other 3.5 features and not realize it until to late?

Comment: This isn't a 3.5 feature.  It was introduced in 2.0 Sp2

Comment: Just going based on the MSDN docs.  Either way, he's using an unpatched version of the Framework, as referenced by his version numbers.  So the code he needs isn't live, so he needs to install it or use the Attribute property.

Comment: @Justin808, unfortunately I can't say that it doesn't.  Which absolutely sucks.  I'm not too familiar with VS Express so I can't say why exactly it's behaving that way.

Comment: @Wes P: according to the MSDN docs HtmlForm.Action is "Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP2, 2.0 SP2" Note the 2.0 SP2 part of that.  Even an RTM 3.5 doesn't have it.

Comment: Missed the print at the bottom of the page.  Fixed my post.

Answer (score 2):

That server version indicates that it has **never had patches applied**.

.42 is the RTM release of .Net 2.0.  ([see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions))
.4955 was released in september of 2010 as a security update.

Before even bothering to figure out exactly what this issue is I would yell and scream at the people responsible for those servers (and their bosses) that every day they put off doing server patches they are putting your company at risk.

There have been a tremendous number of exploits released just in the last few months ([POET was a big one](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/24/update-on-asp-net-vulnerability.aspx)), much less since 2.0 RTM'd, that would allow full access to the servers in question.  And no, McAfee or any other "security" tool or firewall won't stop them.

Sorry to go on about this but there was a reason worms like Code Red and Nimda tore through tens of thousands of servers.  That reason was simply that the people responsible for those servers failed to do their job and apply updates.

---

That said, your issue boils down to you are using 2.0 SP2 locally and your server doesn't have that applied.  [SP2 introduced the HtmlForm.Action attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.action%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  To get SP2 on your production server run windows update.

Comment: This is all valid and gives us a lot to deal with now. Thanks for all the information here!

Answer (score 1):

Version number clarification (this doesn't directly address your question, but is a bit too lengthy for a comment).

There are two .NET version numbers in play: one for the .NET framework (v2, v3.5, v4), and one for the ASP.NET ISAPI DLL (v2 or v4).

You have to set the .NET framework version used for compilation in Visual Studio in your project properties, and the ASP.NET DLL version used by IIS in the website or application pool configuration in the IIS manager (inetmgr.exe).

So, even though your websites are configured to use ASP.NET v2, the applications may (and probably will) use the .NET framework v3.5 or v4.